# Hibernate error org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Table ... doesn't exist

Tags: java, hibernate, invocationtargetexception

Java Student here working on a basic Hibernate project.
Server :tomcat
IDE : Eclipse Juno

I'm trying to persist some data into mySql Db but i've been getting an error every time I click the process button.
The error: **org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Table 'timdowney.requestdatapersistent' doesn't exist**

The name of my DB is : **timdowney** and it DOES exist.
My Db server works fine because i've tested it with other jdbc apps.

So, my question is: why am i getting an error stating that Table 'timdowney.requestdatapersistent' doesn't exist  while timdowney is not a table but my DB name ?

fyi: **requestdatapersistent** is a my bean class

It's a large code, i agree.

```
Button Method Error
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Table 'timdowney.requestdatapersistent' doesn't exist
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at shared.HelperBaseCh4.invokeButtonMethod(HelperBaseCh4.java:155)
    at shared.HelperBaseCh4.executeButtonMethod(HelperBaseCh4.java:124)
    at shared.HelperBaseCh4.executeButtonMethod(HelperBaseCh4.java:133)
    at shared.HelperBaseCh4.executeButtonMethod(HelperBaseCh4.java:100)
    at ch5.persistentData.ControllerHelper.doPost(ControllerHelper.java:128)
    at ch5.persistentData.configure.ControllerHelper.doPost(ControllerHelper.java:40)
    at ch5.persistentData.configure.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Table 'timdowney.requestdatapersistent' doesn't exist
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getDatabaseSnapshot(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1469)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.getDatabaseSnapshot(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:641)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:633)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:629)
    at shared.HibernateHelper.updateDB(HibernateHelper.java:135)
    at ch5.persistentData.ControllerHelper.processMethod(ControllerHelper.java:101)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'timdowney.requestdatapersistent' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2934)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1616)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1708)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3255)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1293)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1428)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 42 more
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/timdowney</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">pasapas2005</property>
    <property name="c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">5</property>
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My Bean Class

```
package ch5.persistentData;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

@Entity
public class RequestDataPersistent extends shared.PersistentBase implements
        Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected String hobby;
    protected String aversion;
    private Long id;

    public RequestDataPersistent() {
    }

    @Id
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    protected void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Pattern(regexp = ".*\\S.*", message = "cannot be empty")
    @NotNull
    public String getHobby() {
        return hobby;
    }

    public void setHobby(String hobby) {
        this.hobby = hobby;
    }

    @Pattern(regexp = ".*\\S.*", message = "cannot be empty")
    @NotNull
    public String getAversion() {
        return aversion;
    }

    public void setAversion(String aversion) {
        this.aversion = aversion;
    }

    protected int daysPerWeek;

    @Min(value = 1, message = "must be greater than 1, if this is a hobby.")
    @Max(value = 7, message = "cannot be greater than 7. A week only has 7 days.")
    public int getDaysPerWeek() {
        return daysPerWeek;
    }

    public void setDaysPerWeek(int daysPerWeek) {
        this.daysPerWeek = daysPerWeek;
    }
}
```

Controller helper class

```
package ch5.persistentData.configure;

import ch5.persistentData.RequestDataPersistent;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import shared.HibernateHelper;

public class ControllerHelper
        extends ch5.persistentData.ControllerHelper {

    public ControllerHelper(
            HttpServlet servlet,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(servlet, request, response);
    }

    static public void initHibernate(HttpServlet servlet) {
    boolean create = 
        Boolean.parseBoolean(servlet.getInitParameter("create"));
        if (create) {
            HibernateHelper.createTable(RequestDataPersistent.class);
        }
        HibernateHelper.initSessionFactory(RequestDataPersistent.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void doGet()
            throws ServletException, java.io.IOException 
    {
        super.doGet();
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost()
            throws ServletException, java.io.IOException 
    {
        super.doPost();
    }
}
```

HiernateHelper class

```
package shared;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

public class HibernateHelper {

    static protected Logger log = Logger
            .getLogger("bytesizebook.webdev.hibernate");
    static protected List<Class> listClasses = new ArrayList<Class>();
    static protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static public void initSessionFactory(Properties props, Class... mappings) {
        if (addMappings(listClasses, mappings)) {
            closeSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
            sessionFactory = createFactory(props, listClasses);
        }
    }

    static public void initSessionFactory(Class... mappings) {
        initSessionFactory(null, mappings);
    }

    static public void createTable(Properties props, Class... mappings) {
        List<Class> tempList = new ArrayList<Class>();
        SessionFactory tempFactory = null;

        addMappings(tempList, mappings);
        if (props == null) {
            props = new Properties();
        }
        props.setProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create");
        tempFactory = createFactory(props, tempList);
        closeSessionFactory(tempFactory);
    }

    static public void createTable(Class... mappings) {
        createTable(null, mappings);
    }

    static protected boolean addMappings(List<Class> list, Class... mappings) {
        boolean bNewClass = false;
        for (Class mapping : mappings) {
            if (!list.contains(mapping)) {
                list.add(mapping);
                bNewClass = true;
            }
        }
        return bNewClass;
    }

    static protected SessionFactory createFactory(Properties props,
            List<Class> list) {
        SessionFactory factory = null;
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        try {
            if (props != null) {
                cfg.addProperties(props);
            }
            configureFromFile(cfg);
            for (Class mapping : list) {
                cfg.addAnnotatedClass(mapping);
            }
            factory = buildFactory(cfg);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            log.error("SessionFactory creation failed.", ex);
            closeSessionFactory(factory);
            factory = null;
            // hibernate has a runtime exception for handling problems with
            // initialisation. Cast the ex to HibernateException and raise,
            // since the root problem is a Hibernate problem.
            throw new HibernateException(ex);
        }
        return factory;
    }

    static protected void configureFromFile(Configuration cfg) {
        try {
            cfg.configure();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            if (ex.getMessage().equals("/hibernate.cfg.xml not found")) {
                log.warn(ex.getMessage());
            } else {
                log.error("Error in hibernate " + "configuration file.", ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

    static protected SessionFactory buildFactory(Configuration cfg)
            throws Exception {
        SessionFactory factory = null;
        try {
            factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            closeSessionFactory(factory);
            factory = null;
            throw ex;
        }
        return factory;
    }

    static public void closeSessionFactory(SessionFactory factory) {
        if (factory != null) {
            factory.close();
        }
    }

    static public void closeFactory() {
        closeSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    }

    static public void updateDB(Object obj) {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            session.saveOrUpdate(obj);

            tx.commit();
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

    static public void updateDB(java.util.List list) {

        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            for (Object obj : list) {
                session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
            }

            tx.commit();
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

    static public void saveDB(Object obj) {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(obj);

            tx.commit();
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

    static public void removeDB(Object obj) {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            session.delete(obj);

            tx.commit();
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

    static public java.util.List getListData(Class classBean, String strKey,
            Object value) {
        java.util.List result = new java.util.ArrayList();

        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(classBean);
            if (strKey != null) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.like(strKey, value));
            }
            result = criteria.list();

            tx.commit();

        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    static public java.util.List getListData(Class classBean, String strKey1,
            Object value1, String strKey2, Object value2) {
        java.util.List result = new java.util.ArrayList();
        boolean withParent = false;
        int age = 0;
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(classBean);
            if (strKey1 != null) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.like(strKey1, value1));
            }
            if (strKey2 != null) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.like(strKey2, value2));
            }

            result = criteria.list();

            tx.commit();

        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    static public java.util.List getListData(Class classBean) {
        return getListData(classBean, null, null);
    }

    static public Object getFirstMatch(Class classBean, String strKey,
            Object value) {

        Object result = null;
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(classBean);
            if (strKey != null) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.like(strKey, value));
            }
            criteria.setMaxResults(1);
            result = criteria.uniqueResult();

            tx.commit();

        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    static public Object getFirstMatch(Object data, String strKey, Object value) {
        return getFirstMatch(data.getClass(), strKey, value);
    }

    static public Object getKeyData(Class beanClass, long itemId) {
        Object data = null;
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        data = session.get(beanClass, itemId);

        session.close();

        return data;
    }

    static public boolean isSessionOpen() {
        return sessionFactory != null;
    }
}
```

new stacktrace after adding @Table annotation in my bean class

```
Button Method Error
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of ch5.persistentData.RequestDataPersistent.id

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at shared.HelperBaseCh4.invokeButtonMethod(HelperBaseCh4.java:155)
    at shared.HelperBaseCh4.executeButtonMethod(HelperBaseCh4.java:124)
    at shared.HelperBaseCh4.executeButtonMethod(HelperBaseCh4.java:133)
    at shared.HelperBaseCh4.executeButtonMethod(HelperBaseCh4.java:100)
    at ch5.persistentData.ControllerHelper.doPost(ControllerHelper.java:128)
    at ch5.persistentData.configure.ControllerHelper.doPost(ControllerHelper.java:40)
    at ch5.persistentData.configure.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of ch5.persistentData.RequestDataPersistent.id
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component$ValueGenerationPlan.execute(Component.java:436)
    at org.hibernate.id.CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.generate(CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:641)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:633)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:629)
    at shared.HibernateHelper.updateDB(HibernateHelper.java:130)
    at ch5.persistentData.ControllerHelper.processMethod(ControllerHelper.java:101)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:65)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: This is the most obvious error message. There is no table `requestdatapersistent` in your database. Annotate your class with `@Table`.

Comment: But, isnt hibernate supposed to create it automatically ?

Comment: Not if you don't tell it what to use as a table using the `@Table` annotation or some xml mapping configuration. You'll have to do the same for the columns.

Comment: Ok i'll try the @table annotation.

Comment: The @Table annotation allows specifying another table name than the default. But it won't create the table. Look for `hibernate.hbm2ddl` in the documentation if you want automatic table creation. Or better, create the table by yourself, using a SQL script.

Comment: I added the @Table annotation but now i'm getting a new error messsage. Please see updated stack trace.

Comment: Ask another, different question, and post the code of shared.PersistentBase.

Comment: Thank you. Everything works fine now. I removed the @Id from the getter  and replaced with: @Column(name="USER_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Table 'timdowney.requestdatapersistent' doesn't exist

Error says schemaname.tablename does not exist, so your schema is timdowney and table name is requestdatapersistent. Since you did not specify any table in Entity it is using bean name as entity name, you need to do either of following:

1. Create a table named requestdatapersistent
2. If there is a different table name then provide in annotation using following:

`@Entity`

`@Table(name="request_data_persistent")`

Hoping this solves your problem.

Cheers !!

Comment: It already looks different. New error : IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of ch5.persistentData.RequestDataPersistent.id

Comment: I added the @Table annotation but now i'm getting a new error messsage. Please see updated stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

if annotation doesn't work for you, you may try creating hibernate mapping file similar to the below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="ch5.persistentData.RequestDataPersistent" 
                 table="tablename" catalog="timdowney ">
        <id name="ID" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="id" length="10" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </id>
        <property name="EventName" type="String">
            <column name="eventname" length="10" not-null="true" unique="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="hobby" type="String">
            <column name="hobby" length="20" not-null="true"
                unique="false" />
        </property>
        ....and so on

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've worked with mapping files before and it worked very well but now want to code using  annotations.